# Android studio unable to run emulator: Process finished with exit code 2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-pixel

I am trying to use an emulator in Android Studio 3.1.4, but I keep getting the error messages:

> Emulator: Could not launch
> 'C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe':
> No such file or directory.

and

> Emulator: Process finished with exit code 2.

This happens with every device I am trying to emulate.

I tried increasing the RAM on the emulator, but it had no effect. Any insight into what my problem is would be great.

Comment: I'd suggest you read [Run apps on the Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator) and [Create and manage virtual devices](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds).

Comment: Have you checked in SDK tools if you have installed Android Emulator?

Comment: I checked, and I do have android emulator installed. If it helps at all, I am trying to use API 23 on a Pixel phone for emulation.

Answer (score 0):

1)Lower your AVD Memory if it set to default try running below 600  MB RAM

2) Try reinstalling the Emulator sdk

Comment: Just lowered the AVD memory to 500 MB RAM and got the same error message. What else do you think might be causing this?

Comment: have You enabled the Virtualisation in Bios in a proper way?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by the following step:

Please ensure "Windows Hypervisor Platform" is installed. If it's not installed, install it, restart your computer and you will be good to go.

[image]